# Solidity, push overrides array

Tags: solidity, web3js, data-types

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;


contract ArraysExample {
   uint[] numbers;

   function addUser() public returns (uint[]) {
      numbers.push(random());
      return numbers;
   }

   function random() private view returns (uint8) {
      return uint8(uint256(keccak256(block.timestamp, block.difficulty))%251);
   }
}
```

When I call the following contracts method

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new 
web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));

const fs = require("fs");
const abi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("abi.json", "utf8")).abi;
const contractAddress = "0x1fba6995e24ffa28bd0d14acd16e6f4cdac8df68";

const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

contractInstance.methods
.addUser() 
.call()
.then(numbers => console.log(numbers));
```

I get this response when I execute the following code instead of ['142', '215', '8' ... ]: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract works.

Here it is Remix, returning an array with multiple items, as expected.

[image]

Your testing methodology is flawed. Specifically, you're using the `.call()` method which is a read-only invocation, like a dry run. It can't update the state. This is why the array isn't growing.

Have a look over here for a more complete explainer: https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Comment: Thank you Rob, that worked for me. I needed to add an event to my contract and emit it. `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
  contractInstance.methods
    .addUser()
    .send({ from: accounts[0] })
    .then(txReceipt => {
      console.log(txReceipt.events.newNumberPushed);
    });
});` it's how my code looks like now.